# Dynamix SQL Error "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: sql, variables, dynamic-sql, variable-declaration

I have the @inAdd1-6 and @inAdd declared.  The @inAdd1-6 will actually be passed into the Stored Procedure.

I will then split them and process the addresses, some as a single address, and others where I compare names, street, zip codes, etc.

I was HOPING I could dynamically change change the @inAdd to each one as I needed to process it  ie `SET @inAdd = @inAdd#`

```
DECLARE
    @id nvarchar(255)        = '[uid]',
    @table      varchar(255) = '[sub_customer]',
    @company    varchar(255) = '',
    @inAdd nvarchar(max)     = '',
    @inAdd1 nvarchar(max)    = 'BLANK,[Invoice Street],BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,[Invoice City],[Invoice State],[Invoice Zip],[Invoice Country]',
    @inAdd2 nvarchar(max)    = '[Shipping Name],[Shipping Street],BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,,[Shipping City],[Shipping State],[Shipping Zip],[Shipping Country]',
   @inAdd3  nvarchar(max)    = '[UPS Company],[UPS Street],BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,,[UPS City],[UPS State],[UPS Zip],[UPS Country]',
   @inAdd4  nvarchar(max)    = '[FedEx Name],[FedEx Street],BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,,[FedEx City],[FedEx State],[FedEx Zip],[FedEx Country]',
   @inAdd5  nvarchar(max)    = 'BLANK,[UPS From Street],BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,,[UPS From City],[UPS From State],[UPS From Zip],[UPS From Country]',
   @inAdd6  nvarchar(max)    = 'BLANK,[FedEx From Street],BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,,[FedEx From City],[FedEx From State],[FedEx From Zip],[FedEx From Country]',

WHILE (@addCnt >= @cnt)
BEGIN
    SET @var = '@inAdd' + CAST(@cnt AS nvarchar(3))
    PRINT @var
    SET @sql = 'SET @inadd = ' + @var
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    ... code to process @inAdd
END
```

The @sql in the PRINT is `SET @inadd = @inAdd1` which is exactly what I want.  However, when I use sp_executesql I get the error.

If put in `SET @inadd = @inAdd1` (or any other @inAdd#) as a separate command it works fine.

Comment: And if you pass in 10000 lines, you declare @inAdd1-10000?

Comment: Where is @cnt defined? And not sure it matters, but at the end of the DECLARE, there seems to be an extra comma at the end of `@inAdd6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute your generated statement with EXEC, so you call a new instance which is not aware of any declarations you made in your base script
You have to add the declarations to your new script

```
WHILE (@addCnt >= @cnt)
BEGIN
    SET @var = '@inAdd' + CAST(@cnt AS nvarchar(3))
    PRINT @var
    SET @sql = 'DECLARE ' + @var + ' nvarchar(50); DECLARE @inadd nvarchar(50); SET @inadd = ' + @var
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    ... code to process @inAdd
END
```

**UPDATE:**
Considering your exact definition of the requirement, I would suggest, you think about other ways of doing it:

1. Import your address data into an import table and then use a sql script to process all rows in this table
2. Code a simple command line tool which processes your addresses (maybe in connection with an sql script to process the single lines)
3. If you are on SQL-Server:

   3.1) Pass your address data as "User-Defined Table Type"

   3.2) Pass your address data as one big string with a seperator und in your script split the string, and insert the result in a temporary table, then process all rows of the table

best regards,
Jimmy

Comment: Except the entire purpose is to set the value to a variable I've already declared and set.  I'm trying to avoid a bunch of `IF (@cnt = 2)  SET @inAdd = @inAdd2` because there could be 50 this time, 10 the next and 10,000 next month.

Comment: But put simple, it's not possibl - Execution is done in a new instance and this instance isn't aware of any declaration done in another instance. Maybe describe what problem you exactly try to solve

Comment: I went with option 1 :)